# MySQL query returning -7 to +7 of current date?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is to possible to run a query on a date column where the date is equal to -7 to +7 of the current date.

Using today (Dec 4th) as the example the query would return from Nov 27th to Dec 11th.

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Karen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course.  Assuming you have a date only (no time component) in the column:

```
where datecol >= curdate() - interval 7 day and
      datecol <= curdate() + interval 7 day
```

With or without a time component, this will work:

```
where datecol >= curdate() - interval 7 day and
      datecol < curdate() + interval 8 day
```

Note that both of these return 15 days of rows.

Comment: Sweet! Works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: where datecol between (curdate() - interval 7 day) and
      (curdate() + interval 7 day)